# filter object with date within the range

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of objects:

```
listings = [{
    title: "Place 1",
    price: "100",
    availability: [
        {
            startDate: "2022-11-15T13:00:00.000Z",
            endDate: "2022-11-23T13:00:00.000Z",
            key: "selection"
        },
        {
            startDate: "2022-11-30T13:00:00.000Z",
            endDate: "2022-12-02T13:00:00.000Z",
            key: "selection"
        },
        {
            startDate: "2022-12-18T13:00:00.000Z",
            endDate: "2022-12-20T13:00:00.000Z",
            key: "selection"
        }
    ]},
    {
     title: "Place 2",
     price: "100",
     availability: [
        {
            startDate: "2022-11-30T13:00:00.000Z",
            endDate: "2022-12-30T13:00:00.000Z",
            key: "selection"
        }]
  }
]
```

And a list

```
range = [
    {
        startDate: "2022-12-01T13:00:00.000Z",
        endDate: "2022-12-25T13:00:00.000Z",
        key: "selection"
    }
]
```

And I would like to get the object side of my listings available during my date range. i.e. startDate smaller than my range[0].startDate and endDate greater than my range[0].endDate.
I have tried doing:

```
listings.filter(listItem => {
  return parseInt(listItem.price) >= parseInt(minPrice) && parseInt(listItem.price) <= parseInt(maxPrice)
}).filter(listItem => {
  return listItem.availability.map((i) => new Date(i.startDate).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) <= new Date(range[0].startDate).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) && new Date(i.endDate).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) >= new Date(range[0].endDate).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0))
})
```

However, it did not filter the listItem with availability outside the range as I was expecting, thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your example complete, so, do you not want overlapping timespans? For example what if listings availability starts before range[0].startDate but does end during range[0]s timespan? Or in other words, do you only want those listings which are available during the full length of range[0]?

Comment: @Jens I only want those listings available during the full length of range[0]

Comment: I also don't get the reason why you set the time to zeros so i haven't added it to my answer yet. Do you accept availabilities when there is half a day missing in range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.filter(...)` should return a boolean for each item, indicating if this item should stay in the list or not. You are returning the result of `.map(...)`, which is an array of transformed values.

If you look at one example: `listings[0].availability.map(a => a.startDate < range[0].startDate)` it returns `Array(3) [ true, true, false ]` and not a single boolean. This array is evaluated to `true` so your listings are all `true` and none is removed.

You could use a filter on availability to remove availablities that are not from interest and then check the resulting availabilities if there are more than zero remaining.

```js
listings.filter(listing => 
    listing.availability.filter(availability => 
        new Date(availability.startDate) <= new Date(range[0].startDate) && new Date(availability.endDate) >= new Date(range[0].endDate))
    .length > 0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried .includes(true) and it worked

Answer (score 0):

`range[0].endDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)`

This expression blows up - you can't invoke `setHours()` on it (because at this point it's a string literal).

What you probably want to do is to turn it into a `Date` instance first:

`new Date(range[0].endDate).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)`

Comment: HI please see my edit, i have turn it into a date but it is still not working

Comment: Check again that it's properly formatted - the last thing you pasted seems to be missing `})` at the end. Also, what are `minPrice` and `maxPrice`?

Comment: sorry that I forgot to include the ```})``` but I'm actually including it in my actual code, min and max price is another filter that filters by ```listItem.price >= minPrice and listItem.price >= maxPrice``` the price filter is working correctly but not the date filter